# Pagewidth table in two-column paper

Tags: tables, document-classes, width

I woud like to make a table almost like the one in the image but I don't know how to do it. It has to be a pagewidth table in a two-column document.
[image]

I've tried with `tabulary`, `tabularx` and `tabular*`, but I'm pretty new to LaTeX. Could you help me with that problem?

My code right now is:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx,epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\bf Simulation study of crystalline phases of \ce{Bi2O3}}
\rhead{ABF}
\lfoot{TFG}
\rfoot{Barcelona, January 2017}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\title{Simulation study of crystalline phases of \ce{Bi2O3}} % HRTEM images
\author{Author: }
\affiliation{}
%\email{} %optional
\author{Advisor:}
%\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
{\bf Abstract:} 
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

%\tableofcontents

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Method}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\subsection{Computational process and algorithm}

First of all we created the conventional cells of the different phases of \ce{Bi2O3} studied. The data required to build those cells is summarized on the

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}
\toprule
Polymorph                            & Crystal structure & Space group & Lattice Parameters                                     & Structural Parameters \\ \midrule
$\alpha$-\ce\{Bi2O3\}                & monoclinic        & P2\_1/C     & =5.849 (5.872)\par b=8.167 (8.126)\par c=7.510 (7.412) &                       \\
$\beta$-\ce\{Bi2O3\}                 & tetragonal        & P-421C      &                                                        &                       \\
$\gamma$-\ce\{Bi2O3\}                & cubic             & I23         &                                                        &                       \\
$\delta$-\ce\{Bi2O3\} (Battle model) & cubic             & Fm-3m       &                                                        &                       \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{acknowledgments}
Be sure to thank your advisor, 
your colleagues, and granting agencies (e.g. parents, etc...) as well.

\end{acknowledgments}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\end{thebibliography}





\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post the code that you have so far, including everything from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. First, we need to know the document class and the various settings; second, we don't want to retype everything. Use the [edit button](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/345917/edit) to add the code.

Comment: To create a twocolumn-wide table in a `twocolumn` document, you should embed the tabular-like material in a `table*` environment. (The `table` environment will span only one column.)

Comment: Please read up on creating a minimal working example (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that); yours was far from minimal, having lots of extraneous packages and formatting that could have confused the real problem.

Answer (score 3):

As @Mico stated you should use `table*`

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table*}[ht]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    A very long & table that must span two columns \\
    Because otherwise it will & not fit in the space provided
    by a single column\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of replacing the "smart" apostrophes you placed around "table*" with backticks.